# Form validation losing variables

Tags: php, validation, variables, forms

Let's say I enter a registration form with this ending URL: `registration.php?accountType=a`
The form is parsed on the same page (registration.php).  If the user doesn't pass form validation they are taken to registration.php with error messages.  So you see I lost my variable accountType=a.  My question:

Can I submit a form for validation and retain the accountType variable?  I'm aware that this could easily be done using a cookie.  I just want a further understanding.

**Solution:** Although all of the answers below were valid, I went with a Session variable and `<form action="registration.php?<?php print 'accountType=' . $_SESSION['accountType']; ?>"` etc.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this in your form:

```
<form action="registration.php?accountType=a">
```

You should use this in your php:

```
if ($validation_success) {
    header('sucess.php')
} else {
    // don't do anything. The page(registration.php?accountType=a) loads
}
```

I'm just giving you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily to it in 3 ways...

1. Using PHP Sessions. Simply do something like

   session_start();
   $_SESSION['namespace'] = array('post' => $_POST, 'get' => $_GET);
2. Using Cookie (Session seems for me to be more elegant).
3. Use Ajax request; it will make your tasks easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the "accountType=$accountType" at the url's end, when you make a http forward, so the user will taken back to the correct page.

I dont see your code, but maybe like this:

```
if(auth())
{
  //do something...
}
else
{
  header("Location: /registration.php?somerror=true&accountType=" . $accountType);
}
```